# How to dynamically alter the onclick values

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, replace, onclick

I have a button that looks like this:

```
<button id="button-1" onclick="adjustValue(1, 1, 30, 1, 'user');">Test</button>
```

The function that I currently have with this button is working properly. However, what can I add to the function to allow it to edit the values of the onclick field?

```
function adjustValue() {
    // Something to alter the field values
}
```

For instance, after the function is ran, I want it to change the onclick field of the button. (The numbers in the example below are random.)

```
<button id="button-1" onclick="adjustValue(1, 2, 60, 1, 'user');">Test</button>
```

I believe I would need to use something with `document.getElementById`. However, I'm still new to JavaScript and I don't know how to accomplish this.

Comment: It's possible, but doesn't make much sense. Rather use a proper event attachment method and variables to change the values of the arguments.

Comment: Your question / need is terribly confusing. Where are these arguments coming from? what do you want to do with them? where would new args come from? have you thought this out?

Comment: `$('#button-1').attr('onclick', "adjustValue(1, 2, 60, 1, 'user');");` but you shouldn't use inline script and for sure, this is not really the way to set parameters...

Comment: Why not do the change inside the `adjustValue()` function itself?

Answer (score 0):

To access the button from the `adjustValue()` you can pass in the parameter `this`. For example:

```
adjustValue(1, 2, 60, 1, 'user', this);
```

The `this` parameter will be the `button#button-1` in which you can change the value of the `<button>`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best approach.

I would rather go for something like this :

```
<button id="button-1" onclick="adjustValue(this);" data-values='["12","b","c"]'>Test</button>
```

And the javascript part :

```
function adjustValue(element) {
    var val = $(element).data("values");
    //Do something with val
    var newValues = [42,"world","hello"];
    $(this).data("values",newValues);
}
```

Or you can also put everything in javascript variables directly :

```
<button id="button-1" onclick="adjustValue();">Test</button>
```

And the javascript :

```
var values = [1,2,3];
function adjustValue() {
    values = [4,5,6];
}
```